# Overloading comparison operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm fairly new to C++ and attempting to overload the < operator in a class.

In my header file I have:

```
friend bool operator<(const Tweet& a, const Tweet& b);
```

and in the class file I have:

```
inline bool Tweet::operator<(const Tweet& a, const Tweet& b) {
    return (a.getID() < b.getID());
}
```

Currently I'm getting an error `‘bool Tweet::operator<(const Tweet&, const Tweet&)’ must take exactly one argument`

Removing the `Tweet::` changes the error to an undefined reference and removing the second argument changes the error to "must take exactly two arguments"

PS - I've tried following the appropriate section in [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/4421719#4421719) as well as a few related questions but then I just get a variety of different errors.

Comment: Just a note, since the function is a friend function it should be able to take the private members so the getters are unnecessary unless I'm not seeing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are declaring a free-standing function to be a friend, and then define a class member function as comparison. That is not exactly right.

If you define the comparison operator having two arguments, you have to declare it static:

```
static bool Tweet::operator<(const Tweet& a, const Tweet& b) {
    return (a.getID() < b.getID());
}
```

This way `a < b` gets interpreted as `Tweet::operator<(a, b);`.

Without `static`, you get implicitly 3 arguments: `*this`, `a` and `b`.

Alternately, you can define an instance operator, taking one argument and comparing it to the current instance:

```
bool Tweet::operator<(const Tweet& b) {
    return (getID() < b.getID());
}
```

This way `a < b` gets interpreted as `a.operator<(b);`.

Alternately, you can define a free-standing function (this is where you actually might need `friend`):

```
bool operator<(const Tweet& a, const Tweet& b) {
    return (a.getID() < b.getID());
}
```

This way `a < b` gets interpreted as `operator<(a, b);`.

Either way is good.

Comment: Thanks, your second suggestion gave errors regarding discarding qualifiers but the third option seems to work great (and it seems all I needed to do was remove the `inline` modifier and the `Tweet::` from my original code)

Comment: @Exupery: you're welcome! Well, for the 2nd suggestion to work, perhaps you need `getID` to be a `const` function.